# Symfony2, FOSUser, don't login user after reset password

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working on resetting password system with FosUser, and I don't know how can I remove the auto-login after user changes his password ?

Thanks for help, I don't want to override, I change directly FOS files.

Comment: Overriding `FOSUserBundle` files is a wrong way to do that

Comment: Make you own FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED listener.  Set the priority so it gets called before the FOSUser listener.  Then remove the autologin logic.  Otherwise, do what @Deynis has suggested.

Comment: can you detail that in an answer ? :)

Comment: why overriding is worse way than change directly FOS files?

Comment: Changing directly FOSUserBundle files is by far the worst way. You cannot upgrade the package any more and you are coupling it with your business logic instead of keeping it separate. Also if you are using Composer you might lose your changes without even noticing, unless you fork their repository, update your Composer configuration to use your own repository and periodically pull the updates from the original repository. Is it worth it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The proper way** :)

Compiler Passes in Symfony allow you to manipulate other services. In this case you want to override `fos_user.listener.authentication` to use your custom subscriber instead of the one provided with FOSUserBundle `FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener`. You can just extends the provided one to subscribe only to the registration events and NOT to the resetting password event:

```
<?php
// src/YourCompany/YourBundle/EventListener/AuthenticationListener.php

namespace YourCompany\YourBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener as FOSAuthenticationListener;

class AuthenticationListener extends FOSAuthenticationListener
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'authenticate',
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'authenticate'
        );
    }

}
```

To do so just define a Compiler Pass like this:

```
<?php
// src/YourCompany/YourBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/FOSUserOverridePass.php

namespace YourCompany\YourBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class FOSUserOverridePass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->getDefinition('fos_user.listener.authentication')->setClass('YourCompany\YourBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationListener');
    }

}
```

And then register your compiler pass in your bundle definition:

```
<?php
// src/YourCompany/YourBundle/YourCompanyYourBundle.php

namespace YourCompany\YourBundle;

use YourCompany\YourBundle\Compiler\FOSUserOverridePass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class YourCompanyYourBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new FOSUserOverridePass());
    }

}
```

That's it!

---

Here's something to read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html

The service you are going to override: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/listeners.xml

And the original class: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/AuthenticationListener.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the bundle, you will have to comment the line 132 in \vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingController.php :

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
```

which disable the auto-login. But as bartek says, it is not a good way to do that.
Although it is only for one line...
I hope it will help you, as I am concerned, I have comment a same line in the regitration by an overloading file on line :

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));
```

To disable the auto-login after the registration.

Comment: Disabling code in the original controller is not consistent (only temporary), after bundle update your "solution" will not be working anymore as it could be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I think I found a light but clean way of doing this : events can be stopped !
check http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html at **Stopping Event Flow/Propagation**.
The event making login after registration seems to be REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, so make a subscriber to this event with a high priority

```
...
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => ['onRegistrationCompleted',9999],
    );
}
public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event) {
    // this trick prevent login now
    $event->stopPropagation();
}
```

Then if you fear that some important listener/subscribers loose the event, adjust the listen priority...

Answer (score 0):

I also used a kind of similar solution as @David suggested. My requirement was that only Admin can create users and if user successfully created it should redirect to the list of the users page.

What I have done is that I have handled two/three event. The first one REGISTRATION_SUCCESS where I attached my custom redirect URL to the event as below (also mentioned in the doc):

```
 public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [
            ['onRegistrationSuccess', -10],
        ],
    ];


}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event) {
    $url = $this->router->generate('list_all_users');

    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
}
```

And if you look at the code of FOSUserbundle RegistrationController after success two more events has been dispatching REGISTRATION_CONFIRM/ED. So I handled these events and have stopped them:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => ['stopEvent', 9999],
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => ['stopEvent', 9999],

    );;


}

public function stopEvent(FilterUserResponseEvent $event) {

    $event->stopPropagation();
}
```

Hope this could help someone.